# How to add a Height property to a custom React Component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Hey I am creating a React Form which has two TextBoxes. I have created a Custom Textbox but I want them of different height how can I achieve this ?

form.js

```
 <Label>Job Description</Label>
            <Textarea
              type="textarea"
              name="description"
              focus={isFocused}
              value={description}
              onFocus={handleOnFocus}
              onChange={handleTitleChange}
            />
            <Label>Job Requirements</Label>
            <Textarea
              type="textarea"
              name="requirement"
              focus={isFocused}
              value={requirement}
              onFocus={handleOnFocus}
              onChange={handleTitleChange}
            />
```

styled component

```
const Textarea = styled.textarea`
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;
  height: 80px;
  background-color:white;

`;
```

Right now I have assigned the height to 80px but I want the `Job requirement` text box to be 40px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it via props

```
<Textarea type="textarea" name="description" height="40px" />
<label>Job Requirements</label>
<Textarea type="textarea" name="requirement" height="80px" />
```

and then

```
const Textarea = styled.textarea`
 width: 100%;   
 border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
 outline: none;  
 resize: none; 
 transition: 0.1s ease-out; 
 height: ${(props) => props.height};  
 background-color: white; `;
```

Check my
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-sgd24?)

Comment: thnx a ton mate

Answer (score -1):

Add in this line to where you've declared your styled component Textarea beneath your other styling,

```
  ${props => props.smallTextBox && css`
    height: 40px;
  `}
```

and then when you declare your component

```
<Textarea
  smallTextBox
  type="textarea"
  ...otherProps
/>
```